# Automatically deleteting old IntelliTrace recordings

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, intellitrace

I recently noticed that I collected 22GB worth of IntelliTrace recordings. Sadly, I was unable to find a location in the IntelliTrace settings that would allow me to automatically delete them.
Is there an solution to this in Visual Studio or do I have to take care of this myself?

**edit**: As Hans Passant suggested, I submitted a [suggestion](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/581093/periodically-delete-intellitrace-recordings) to connect.microsoft.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no setting that will automatically cleanup the IntelliTrace files. Wait for SP1.

Comment: Yeah, it seems like it :( This must be the easiest rep you earned yet :P

Answer (score 4):

You can specify the location of the IntelliTrace files in VS2012 settings...

> Tools --> Options --> IntelliTrace --> Advanced.

Choose "*Store IntelliTrace recordings in this directory*" and tell it where you want to store the files.

Now you have a few options for deleting the files. You can write a Powershell script... or you can jump over to the Wintellect GitHub page https://github.com/Wintellect/WintellectPowerShell and grab John Robbins' Powershell scripts.

There is a command in there called "*Remove-IntelliTraceFiles*".

Et voila!

Answer (score 0):

Stopping and starting your vm on azure will clear the log.

Comment: Perhaps you should elaborate a little more on why this does so. :)